# Projectile acceleration with quadratic drag and coriolis force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag, coriolis-effect

I'm wondering if this equations for the acceleration of a projectile in the x, y and z directions are correct, if we take into account the square law of resistance and the Coriolis force. The projectile would be launched at a certain angle from the northern hemisphere from north to south, with some initial velocity.
Do I just combine them to get the equations of motion? Thanks for help
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please make a self-contained question. You should avoid relying on external links to make the questions intelligible, as the link could break in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is x,y,z projectile fixed coordinate system ?

Comment: @Eli yes coordinate system is fixed. Projectile is launched at (0,0,0). X coordinate is pointing at south, y at east and z is pointing outwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your equations are consistent with your coordinate system. Let the projectile be launched only in the x-z plane. Then $\vec{\Omega} = (-\Omega \cos(\phi), 0, \Omega \sin(\phi))$ in your coordinate system ($\phi$ is the angle from equator, x points south, y east, z outward), so $\dot{\vec{r}} \times \vec{\Omega} = (\dot{y} \Omega \sin(\phi), -\dot{z} \Omega \cos(\phi) - \dot{x} \Omega \sin(\phi), -\dot{y} \Omega \cos(\phi))$. Hence, your coriolis equations should be $$\ddot{x} = 2 \Omega v_y \sin(\phi)$$ $$\ddot{y} = -2\Omega(v_z \cos(\phi) + v_x \sin(\phi))$$ $$\ddot{z} = 2 \Omega v_y \cos(\phi)$$

Gravity should not be included in the coriolis equations. Assuming that your $g$ is the observed free-fall acceleration (gravity force + centrifugal), that your object has the same cross-sectional area and drag coefficients in all three x,y,z directions (and $v_x$ in equation 3 should be $v_z$), then you can use Newton's Law $\ddot{\vec{r}} = \vec{g} + \text{ coriolis } + \vec{F}_{drag}/M$ for each coordinate (let $\gamma = C_d \rho A/(2M)$) to get your equations of motion:

$$\ddot{x} = 2 \Omega v_y \sin(\phi) - \gamma |v| v_x$$
$$\ddot{y} = -2 \Omega (v_z \cos(\phi) + v_x \sin(\phi)) - \gamma |v| v_y$$
$$\ddot{z} = 2 \Omega v_y \cos(\phi) - g - \gamma |v| v_z$$